# Get external website content using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, metadata

In my website I am using node js for backend and html for front end. I need to get external website metadata (keywords).

Have any package for get the metadata in node js?

For example i have 100 website url in array following like this.

```
var arrayName = ["http://www.realsimple.com/food-recipes/9-healthy-predinner-snacks", "http://www.womenshealthmag.com/weight-loss/100-calorie-snacks", "https://www.pinterest.com/explore/healthy-snacks/", "http://www.rd.com/slideshows/healthy-snacks-for-adults/", "http://greatist.com/snacking", "http://www.bodybuilding.com/fun/26-best-healthy-snacks.html"]
```

I need to get all website metadata particularly in keywords of metadata.
In node js have any package for this ?

I found some code in google.

```
var options = {
host: 'www.google.com',
port: 80,
path: '/index.html'
};

http.get(options, function(res) {
console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
}).on('error', function(e) {
console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```

Have any other options?

Expected Outputs:

```
Array1 = ["keyword1","keyword2","keyword3"];
Array2 = ["keyword1","keyword2","keyword3"];
Array3 = ["keyword1","keyword2","keyword3"];
```

Array1, Array2, Array3 are Site1,Site2,Site3 like this.

Comment: Try cheerio module. https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest you to use any from following packages:

- http://npm.im/cheerio
- http://npm.im/request

> **Note:** You need to code it by yourself to grasp keywords from site data.

Comment: Note: Request is now deprecated.